# Header covers Content Section after click on a menu link (One Page Site)

Tags: html

I have a fixed header on my "One Page" Website. When you click on a menu item 
`<a href="#itemone">Item One</a>` 
it goes to the section.

The Header has a height of 50px and it covers a part of the content.

Does anyone have a solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/SUP4d/

Comment: Yes we do have, if you provide a working demo/[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SUP4d/

Answer (score 0):

Try add `55px` to `margin-top` (or `padding-top`) for `body`, and set `top: 0;` to the fixed header.

```
body, html {
  margin-top: 55px;
}
```